# How do you import all sass files in a directory using Parceljs (aka Globbing)

Tags: sass, parceljs

When I try to import all the contents of a directory using globbing with the Parceljs bundler it gives me an error. It gives me the "File to import not found or unreadable" error. I was under the impression that Parcel handles the configuration for this kind of setup for you. I am attempting to import my partials like so:

```
@import './someDirectoryName/*'
```

Is there something that I need to configure for Parceljs to import the contents of the directory?